# Can't use event with removeEventlistener: 'e is undefined' (Firefox)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently doing one of OdinProject's assignment, where I have to create a grid of div you can color with your mouse, but I've hit a block along the way.

Here's a working version of my code. I could explain what this code do, but it is pretty straightforward. It works on jsfiddle so  so I feel it'd be best for you to try it yourself

```js
//creating the div grid:
let mainDiv =document.createElement('div');
mainDiv.classList.add('grid')
mainDiv.textContent="";

for (i=0;i<16*16;i++){
 let tempDiv=document.createElement('div')
 tempDiv.textContent=i;
  mainDiv.appendChild(tempDiv)
 } 


//create the mouseover event that changes the BgroundColor
let gridNode=mainDiv.querySelectorAll('div');
mainDiv.addEventListener("mouseover",  ()=> {
  gridNode.forEach( div => {
    if (event.target===div) div.classList.add('bk-gd-red');
  }) 
}) 


//creating the button
document.body.appendChild(mainDiv)
let newbutton=document.createElement('button')
newbutton.textContent="reset"
document.body.insertBefore(newbutton, mainDiv);

//creating the click event assoc. to the button
newbutton.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
 gridNode.forEach(div => 
  div.classList.remove('bk-gd-red'));
 let newRows=prompt('How many square per side?')
 mainDiv.style.gridTemplateColumns= `repeat( ${newRows},1fr)`
 mainDiv.removeEventListener('mouseover', mumu)




})
```

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(16,1fr);
    margin: 0 10% 

}
.bk-gd-red {
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Page Title</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    </head>
    <body> 

  </body>
</html>
```

Now, onto the question: If you have tried this code, you may have noticed that after clicking the button and answering the prompt with a number, your mouse cursor may end up standing on the grid. If so, the background will immediately be colored red upon exiting the question box, which is inconvenient.

To avoid it, I wanted to add a removeEventListener upon a button click that will remove the coloring event from the listener, and integrate it again upon mouseleave by re-adding the coloring event.
So first, I would need to use a named function for the coloring event. This is where I'm stuck.

Here the piece of code I conjured to create that effect:

```
//creating an external function for the event
  function mumu(Node, e){
    Node.forEach( div=> {
      if (event.target===div) div.classList.add('bk-gd-red');
          })
  
  }
//modifying my code to include that function
  let gridNode=mainDiv.querySelectorAll('div');
  mainDiv.addEventListener("mouseover",  mumu(gridNode,e));
```

I've tried everything I can think of with the 'e': removing it, adding it everywhere, calling the mumu function using e.target as a parameter instead of 'e'... All I get is either "'e' is undefined" or "Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "target", e is undefined"

I cannot figure out why I can't use e.target or how to use 'e'.

So here are my questions:

1. why do I get these types of error and how to fix it
2. is the practice of removing and re-adding event from the listener on the fly good practice, or are there better one out there?

Comment: Cannot reproduce.

Comment: `mumu(gridNode, e)` immediately executes `mumu`. But there's no `e` at that place and time -> `ReferenceError: e is undefined`

Comment: Sure, but then I've tried with mainDiv.addEventListener("mouseover",  mumu(gridNode,e.target)); but it didn't work either(the mumu function was modified accordingly). I don't understand why I get an "e is undefined" error when I use events inside a addEventListener method

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Andreas's comment, I was able to figure out a solution.

What I did:

```
//new mumu
 function mumu(e){
  let gridNode=document.getElementById('main-div').querySelectorAll('div');
  gridNode.forEach( div => {
      if (e.target===div) div.classList.add('bk-gd-red');
  })
}

//event function mumu called without passing arguments
  let gridNode=mainDiv.querySelectorAll('div');
  mainDiv.addEventListener("mouseover",  mumu);
```

It required either using a global variable or IDing the main div containing the grid. I suppose IDing is a more common and safer practice so I did just that.

here's the rest of the code if anyone is curious. it works like a charm.

```
document.body.appendChild(mainDiv)
let newbutton=document.createElement('button')
newbutton.textContent="reset"
document.body.insertBefore(newbutton, mainDiv);
let gridNode=document.getElementById('main-div').querySelectorAll('div');

newbutton.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
 gridNode.forEach(div => 
  div.classList.remove('bk-gd-red'));

 let newRows=prompt('How many square per side?')
 mainDiv.style.gridTemplateColumns= `repeat( ${newRows},1fr)`
 mainDiv.removeEventListener('mouseover', mumu)
 mainDiv.addEventListener('mouseleave', (e)=> {
   mainDiv.addEventListener('mouseover', mumu)
 })
})
```